# Como ler um arquivo no mesmo diretório do script usando Lua

Tags: arquivo, lua

Tô tentando fazer um pequeno script, mas estou enfrentando algumas dificuldades

```lua
local lab = nil
local f = io.open("/input-lab.txt", "r")
print(f)
```

Eu queria abrir um arquivo que ta no mesmo diretório do script e conseguir ler os dados dele, digamos que `input-lab.txt` tivesse os seguintes dados

```
111101
100001
101101
101001
101111
```

Daí eu queria esse arquivo de alguma forma e conseguir gerar uma `string` baseada nele tipo

```lua
"111101\n100001\n101101\n101001\n101111"
```

Mas não tô conseguindo fazer o script ler o arquivo no mesmo diretório, como faço isso?

Comment: no diretório onde está o script, ou no diretório corrente ? se for no diretório corrente é fácil, é só colocar "input-lab.txt" ou "./input-lab.txt"...se for especificamente no diretório do script acho que não tem um jeito fácil (lembre-se que você pode estar no diretório /x/y/x e o script estar no diretório /a/b/c)

Comment: o que seria o diretorio corrente é como eu sei?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso:

```
for linhas in io.lines("input-lab.txt") do
    print(linhas)
end
```

ou

```
local f = "input-lab.txt"

for linhas in io.lines(f) do
    print(linhas)
end
```

ou

```
local f = io.lines("input-lab.txt")

for linhas in f do
    print(linhas)
end
```

Todos eles retornarão:

```
111101
100001
101101
101001
101111
```

caso esse arquivo esteja em uma pasta coloque

```
pastadoarquivo/arquivo.txt
ou pastadoarquivo/outrapasta/arquivo.txt
```